# EXCEL Formula to return a SUM for a different date range (in ROW) and a different product (in COLUMN)

Tags: arrays, dynamic, excel, sum, vba

I have a spreadsheet of product sales by day. There are thousands of Products that were updated on different days. Each Product is in a separate column (designated by a Product ID). Each row is a different day.

I am looking for a formula that will sum the sales for each product since the day it was updated.

So there are 2 moving parts for the formula, identifying which column to sum by the product ID, and then sum from the date it was updated onwards. I have been able to isolate the Date row using

```
*=MATCH(F159,Sheet!A:A,0)*
```

and the Column reference using

```
*=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,K159,4,1,),"1","")*
```

but I haven't been able to incorporate these into a formula that will then sum.

Any help would be grreatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Would your last date updated include all the data in the sheet, manually entered, or automatically calculated?

Comment: trying to paint the picture of your data... So column headers are productIDs, and dates are in rows below the ids, where is the qty located? Is the last date in the column the last date updated? Where is Qty, Last date updated located? Could you add screen shots or sample of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to do with a `SUMIF` formula, so assuming you have a specific product in column H then you can use this formula to sum for that product for sales on and after a specific date

`=SUMIF(A:A,">="&Y2,H:H)`

where your reference date is in Y2

Now you want the product to be dynamic too so with a specific product in Z2 you can expand that SUMIF like this to get the sum column dynamically

`=SUMIF(A:A,">="&Y2,INDEX(B:X,0,MATCH(Z2,B$1:X$1,0)))`

so that will find the correct column to sum, assuming product data in columns B to X (expand as required) with product name in row 1

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions as to your variable formats, try this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    row = MATCH(F159,Sheet!A:A,0)
    col = SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,K159,4,1,),"1","")
    lastrow = Range(col).End(xlDown).Row

    Set rng = Range(col & Row & ":" & col & lastrow)

    Range("B1").Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try PivotTables in Excel?